# Deserializing json in c# for the nest-api

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, nest-api

I am trying trying to Deserialize the Devices json structure below with c#, newtonsoft, and .net 3.5, put have been unable to produce code that works as the "qxdddh" and "q0tL6au" are dynamically generated names.

Ultimately creating a list or array of thermostat classes for each thermostat in the structure (in this case "qxdddh" and "q0tL6au").

```
{
    "thermostats": {
        "qxdddh": {
            "locale": "en-US",
            "temperature_scale": "F",
            "is_using_emergency_heat": false,
            "has_fan": true,
            "software_version": "4.1",
            "has_leaf": true,
            "device_id": "qxdddh",
            "name": "",
            "can_heat": true,
            "can_cool": true,
            "hvac_mode": "heat",
            "target_temperature_c": 12.5,
            "target_temperature_f": 55,
            "target_temperature_high_c": 24.0,
            "target_temperature_high_f": 75,
            "target_temperature_low_c": 20.0,
            "target_temperature_low_f": 68,
            "ambient_temperature_c": 21.0,
            "ambient_temperature_f": 70,
            "away_temperature_high_c": 24.0,
            "away_temperature_high_f": 76,
            "away_temperature_low_c": 12.5,
            "away_temperature_low_f": 55,
            "structure_id": "ryWu-tRQstxux0tYhmZ8ESsrGgDjDQ",
            "fan_timer_active": false,
            "name_long": "Thermostat",
            "is_online": true
        },
        "q0tL6au": {
            "locale": "en-US",
            "temperature_scale": "F",
            "is_using_emergency_heat": false,
            "has_fan": true,
            "software_version": "4.1",
            "has_leaf": true,
            "device_id": "q0tL6au",
            "name": "Den",
            "can_heat": false,
            "can_cool": true,
            "hvac_mode": "off",
            "target_temperature_c": 20.5,
            "target_temperature_f": 69,
            "target_temperature_high_c": 24.0,
            "target_temperature_high_f": 75,
            "target_temperature_low_c": 20.0,
            "target_temperature_low_f": 68,
            "ambient_temperature_c": 23.0,
            "ambient_temperature_f": 73,
            "away_temperature_high_c": 24.0,
            "away_temperature_high_f": 76,
            "away_temperature_low_c": 12.5,
            "away_temperature_low_f": 55,
            "structure_id": "ryWu-tqNu0tYhmZ8ESsrGgDjDQ",
            "fan_timer_active": false,
            "name_long": "Den Thermostat",
            "is_online": true
        }
    }
}
```

The initial attempt of code was

```
    public class Devices
    {
        public TstatDetails[] thermostats { get; set; }
    }

    public class TstatDetails
    {
         public string locale { get; set; }
         public string temperature_scale { get; set; }
         public string is_using_emergency_heat { get; set; }
         public string has_fan { get; set; }
         public string software_version { get; set; }
         public string has_leaf { get; set; }
         public string device_id { get; set; }
         public string name { get; set; }
         public string can_heat { get; set; }
         public string can_cool { get; set; }
         public string hvac_mode { get; set; }
         public string target_temperature_c { get; set; }
         public string target_temperature_f { get; set; }
         public string target_temperature_high_c { get; set; }
         public string target_temperature_high_f { get; set; }
         public string target_temperature_low_c { get; set; }
         public string target_temperature_low_f { get; set; }
         public string ambient_temperature_c { get; set; }
         public string ambient_temperature_f { get; set; }
         public string away_temperature_high_c { get; set; }
         public string away_temperature_high_f { get; set; }
         public string away_temperature_low_c { get; set; }
         public string away_temperature_low_f { get; set; }
         public string structure_id { get; set; }
         public string fan_timer_active { get; set; }
         public string name_long { get; set; }
         public string is_online { get; set; }
    }
```

and

```
Devices tstats = (Devices) Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Devices>(jsonstring);
```

Which produces and exception with the following description

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"})
>   into type 'NestTest.NestOAuth2+TstatDetails[]' because the type
>   requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
>
> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g.
>   [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET
>   type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type
>   like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object.
>   JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to
>   deserialize from a JSON object.

I understand the error (i think) but being fairly new to c# am unsure on how to correct for this scenario.

Comment: Thanks for providing enough code for us to help you - but could you reduce it to just a few properties? That would make everything simpler.

Comment: @user2761903 how did you managed to retrieve the Json?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change your `Devices` class to use a `Dictionary<,>` instead of an array:

```
public class Devices
{
    public Dictionary<string, TstatDetails> thermostats { get; set; }
}
```

JSON.NET will interpret each property of the `thermostats` object in the JSON as an entry in the dictionary, and populate it appropriately. (Your calling code remains exactly the same.)

Then you'll have all the thermostats available by ID. For example:

```
TstatDetails details = tstats["qxdddh"];
```

Once that's working, I'd strongly recommend you try to make all the property names more conventional :)

Answer (score 0):

Your Json object should be an array, not just an object.

It should basically be wrapped with `[ .... ]` (of which within you can definitely have multiple *objects*) rather than `{ ... }`.

It should probably look similar to this:

```
[
        {
            "locale": "en-US",
            "temperature_scale": "F",
            "is_using_emergency_heat": false,
            ...
        },
        {
            "locale": "en-US",
            "temperature_scale": "F",
            "is_using_emergency_heat": false,
            ...
        }
]
```

**EDIT**

OK, I can't compete with The Skeet.
But I'll leave my answer because it's correct as well (just one option to attack the problem).

Comment: Used Jon's answer above, but that for this info also.